# Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroupId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to provision an Application Load Balancer, but got an error:

> Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroupId

My CloudFormation template is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for creating LoadBalancer

Parameters:
  VPC2Block:
    Description: VPCId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0c9a732125ac08541
  
  PublicSubnet03Block:
    Description: SubnetId of an existing subnet (for the primary network in your Virtual Private Cloud VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-0787f34404852ceb9

Resources:
  
  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      Name: MyApplicationLoadBalancer
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroupId: !Ref Albsg 
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet03Block
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: ALB

  HTTPListener:
        Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
        Properties:
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
            Port: 80
            Protocol: "HTTP"
            DefaultActions: 
              - Type: forward
                TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
  
  
  ALBTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: 200,302
      Name: MyWebServers
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: instance
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      VpcId: !Ref VPC2Block
      

  Albsg:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupName: ALB-sg
      GroupDescription: Security group for Load balancer
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '80'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: '80'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name 
          Value: ALB_SG

Outputs:
  TargetGroupName:
    Value: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
    Description: Name of Target ARN
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly. Also I already answers you before for the issue with security groups.

Comment: Please consult the documentation before posting questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html) documentation shows:

```yaml
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
Properties: 
  IpAddressType: String
  LoadBalancerAttributes: 
    - LoadBalancerAttribute
  Name: String
  Scheme: String
  SecurityGroups: 
    - String
  SubnetMappings: 
    - SubnetMapping
  Subnets: 
    - String
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  Type: String
```

Your template has `SecurityGroupId`, which is not defined.

Perhaps you intended to use `SecurityGroups`?